# show that $y_1$ is a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

show: if $y_1$ is a solution to 3rd order linear homogeneous equation $y'''+p_2(x)y''+p_1(x)y'+p_0(x)y = 0 $ (1) and $y_2 = u(x)y_1(x)$ then $v =u'$ satisfies 2nd order linear homogeneous DE

So far...

- I took $y_2 ' $, $y_2''$, and $y_2'''$ and substitues into the above formula (1)
- how do we end up showing $v =u'$ satisfies 2nd order linear homogeneous DE? Any hints?

Comment: After substituting in the derivatives of $y_{2}$, factoring $u, u', u''$ and $u'''$ and noting that the ODE with $u$ factored is the given ODE and hence $0$, you end up with $$u''' (y_{1}) + u''(3y_{1}' + p_{2}y_{1}) + u'(3y_{1}'' + 2p_{2}y_{1}' + p_{1}y_{1}) = 0$$ Making the substitution $v = u'$ gives you a second order ODE in $v$.

Comment: after substitution i get: $u′′′(y_1)+u′′(3y_1'+p_2y_1)+u′(3y_1''+2p_2y_1'+p_1y_1)+u(y_1'''+p_2y_1''+p_1y_1'+p_0y_1)=0$

Comment: $y_{1}''' + p_{2}y_{1}'' + p_{1}y_{1}' + p_{0}y_{1} = 0$

Comment: what happens to $p_0y_1$

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: why does your solution after factoring u, u', u'', u''' doesnt have $u(y′′′_1+p_2y′′_1+p_1y′_1+p_0y_1)$

Comment: I've stated it twice now. $y_{1}$ is a solution to the ODE and so

$$y_{1}''' + p_{2}y_{1}'' + p_{1}y_{1}' + p_{0}y_{1} = 0$$